# найти список строк в строке

Tags: c#

Поясняю, есть некий список строк

```
List<string>Separator = new List<string>();
Separator.Add("0000");
Separator.Add("1111");
Separator.Add("2222");
Separator.Add("3333");
```

И есть строка  - _String. в ней надо найти все последовательности из списка Separator
написал такой код

```
foreach (string str in Separator)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i != -1;)
    {
        i = _String.IndexOf(str, i + 4);
        if (i != -1)
            SeparatorInt.Add(i);
    }     
}
```

Программа находит все последовательности, кроме той которая будет в самом начале (начинаться в первых четырех символах _String).
Подскажите как поменять код, что бы прога искала и в первых четырех символах?

Comment: Замените `int i = 0;` на `int i = -4;`.

Comment: спасибо помогло

Comment: @polsok, теперь ваш ход.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в самой первой итерации цикла, при `i = 0`, стартовая позиция для поиска во втором аргументе метода `IndexOf` равна 4.

Просто замените `int i = 0` на `int i = -4`, и первый поиск будет выполняться, начиная с позиции `0` в строке:

```
foreach (string str in Separator)
{
    for (int i = -4; i != -1;)
    {
        i = _String.IndexOf(str, i + 4);
        if (i != -1)
            SeparatorInt.Add(i);
    }     
}
```